# How can I render an image to the browser rather than force it to download?

Tags: php, laravel, dompdf

I'm using Azure blob storage to house images and DOMPdf to create PDF files. The issue I'm facing is that DOMPdf will not "Download files" to display them. My current controller, contacts Azure blob storage, grabs the file and spits it out as a download.

Instead, I have tried to use the `response()->file()` method in Laravel to display the image instead:

```
// Assume $file holds the file content from Azure Blob Storage
\Illuminate\Support\Facades\File::append(Storage::disk('local')->path("chunks/{$fileToken}"), $file);
$mimeType = mime_content_type(Storage::disk('local')->path("chunks/{$fileToken}"));


# Check if we can render this as an image
if (in_array($mimeType, ['image/jpeg','image/gif','image/png','image/bmp','image/svg+xml'])) {
    $headers = [
        'Content-Type' => $mimeType,
        'Content-Disposition' => sprintf('inline; filename="%s"', $realPath->filename)
    ];

    $response = response()->file(Storage::disk('local')->path("chunks/{$fileToken}"), $headers);

    # Delete from local disk
    \Illuminate\Support\Facades\File::delete(Storage::disk('local')->path("chunks/{$fileToken}"));

     return $response;
}

# Delete from local disk
\Illuminate\Support\Facades\File::delete(Storage::disk('local')->path("chunks/{$fileToken}"));

// Do normal download functionality
```

Now, the `mime_content_type` successfully identifies the PNG I am trying, it creates the file in the `chunks` directory and if I remove the delete, I can open it as the PNG perfectly fine. The issue I'm getting is the browser is not rendering the image. Infact, it is rendering the headers?

[image]

How can I render this image out to the browser so I can then access the image in DOMPdf?

Comment: I guess you really need to concentrate on the showing of an image only. Try to make a complete code example, that reproduces the problem.

Comment: That will reproduce the problem, just put any file content inside of a variable named `$data` with that code, replace the `$fileToken` with any value and its reproduceable - but I've earmarked the question as related to DomPDF as I guess it solves the current issue that this is kind of associated too and I appreciate the help :D  @KIKOSoftware